# display elements inside div inline using css

Tags: html, css

I want display elements inside div inline but not getting success

```
<div class="main_support1">
<label> Full name *<br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name *"></span></label><br>
       <label> Email Address *<br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address *"></span></label>
 </div>
```

If anyone have idea then let me know

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific or include an image how your result should look like?

Comment: Let us know what's your "idea".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update the main_support1 class to include the following

```
.main_support1{
  display: flex;
}
```

This will position your input groups horizontally

Comment: Not sure why my answer is being down-voted...it works https://codepen.io/jriches/pen/eYWqPBZ